# How to use mapStateToProps from angular6?

Tags: angular, redux, react-redux

I am a React Lover , I am Implementing Redux in Angular Application, But I have an issue with get store data using mapStateToProps , How to do that ?

> It is throwing an error store_1.connect is not a function

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux, NgReduxModule, connect } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { IAppState, rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE } from './store';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgReduxModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
    constructor (ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
            ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>  {
   console.log(state);
   return {
     state
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AppModule);
```

Comment: In react-redux there is a method called mapStateToProps , I was trying that , Actually the error originated from angular-redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `connect` here. When you work with Angular you mostly deal with Observables from rxjs.

`@angular-redux/store` library uses [Select Pattern](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/select-pattern.md) to access store because it plug in very efficiently to Angular's change detection mechanism.

It gives us two options:

**The @select decorator**

```
// this selects `counter` from the store and attaches it to this property
// it uses the property name to select, and ignores the $ from it
@select() counter$;

// this selects `counter` from the store and attaches it to this property
@select() counter;

// this selects `counter` from the store and attaches it to this property
@select('counter') counterSelectedWithString;

// this selects `pathDemo.foo.bar` from the store and attaches it to this
// property.
@select(['pathDemo', 'foo', 'bar']) pathSelection;

// this selects `counter` from the store and attaches it to this property
@select(state => state.counter) counterSelectedWithFunction;

// this selects `counter` from the store and multiples it by two
@select(state => state.counter * 2)
counterSelectedWithFuntionAndMultipliedByTwo: Observable<any>;
```

**Injecting NgRedux instance in constructor**(thanks to [Angular DI](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)):

```
import * as CounterActions from '../actions/CounterActions';
import { NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';

@Component({
    selector: 'root',
    template: `
  <counter [counter]="counter$| async"
    [increment]="increment"
    [decrement]="decrement">
  </counter>
  `
})
export class Counter {
  private count$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let {increment, decrement } = CounterActions;
    this.counter$ = this.ngRedux.select('counter');
  }

  incrementIfOdd = () => this.ngRedux.dispatch(
    <any>CounterActions.incrementIfOdd());

  incrementAsync = () => this.ngRedux.dispatch(
    <any>CounterActions.incrementAsync());
}
```

You can think of this pattern like an efficient analogue to `reselect` for the RxJS-heavy Angular world.

For complete example see [**example-app**](https://github.com/angular-redux/example-app) or **[simple counter example](https://github.com/angular-redux/system-js-example)**

Comment: This is the proper way of subscribe store , Thanks :)